# get package description before loading runtime package

Tags: delphi, package

Using Delphi 10.2.3, I have a handful of runtime-load packages that I want to get the package's Description from the BPL before loading it so that I can notify the user that I'm loading that package.  How do I access the package's Description before I load the package?  It's not in the FileDescription field of the versioninfo.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetBplDescription(const AFileName: string): string;
var
    libHandle: THandle;
    resStream: TResourceStream;
begin
    Result := '';
    libHandle := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(AFileName), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    if (libHandle <> 0) then
    begin
        resStream := TResourceStream.Create(libHandle, 'DESCRIPTION', RT_RCDATA);
        try
            if (resStream.Size > 0) then
            begin
                SetLength(Result, resStream.Size);
                resStream.Read(Result[1], resStream.Size);
            end;
        finally
            resStream.Free;
            FreeLibrary(LibHandle);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

*System.SysUtils* provides *function GetPackageDescription* for that. It is even documented: [System.SysUtils.GetPackageDescription](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.GetPackageDescription)

> Returns the description resource of a package.
>
> Call GetPackageDescription to obtain the description stored with the
> named package. If the package does not have a description resource,
> GetPackageDescription returns an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, Uwe.  I had missed that function when I looked through SysUtils.